# Where not equal to substrings array

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables, one called cmdr_group and one called groupUser. I am attempting to get a list of all the groups this user is not in, which is proving to be fairly difficult. GroupUser has multiple users for each group, each with their own id.

Now I understand why this query won't work but I am putting it here to demonstrate my thought process.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.userID
FROM cmdr_group t1
LEFT JOIN groupUser t2 ON t2.groupID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.ID != (SELECT groupID FROM groupUser WHERE userID=90792652);
```

If you need any information as to what is in the tables just let me know.

Comment: just change != to NOT IN.  So your condition clause should be:   WHERE t1.ID NOT IN (SELECT groupID FROM groupUser WHERE userID=90792652);

Comment: "substrings array"? Huh? if the subselect is returning multiple values, then you have to use `not in`, not `!=`.

Comment: What do you mean "has multiple users for each group"?  Provide some sample data.

Comment: Yeah it worked cheers @devlincarnate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I think I understand.  I would approach this using `not exists` or `not in`:

```
select g.*
from cmdr_group g
where not exists (select 1
                  from groupuser gu
                  where gu.userID = 90792652 and
                        gu.groupId = g.Id
                 );
```

This query basically follows your question.  The overall query is fetching all groups.  The `not exists` is just checking that the user is not in the group.

Comment: perhaps this should be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @devlincarnate . . . I totally changed the answer.